# how to evaluate the index of a loop in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Say I have a loop:

```
for j in 0 to 9 loop
  if  j <= natutalValue then
    -- do stuff;
  end if ;
end loop;
```

When I write the code this way the compiler isn't happy about it.

My question: Can I evaluate NATURAL ?

Comment: Can you please clarify "isn'T happy about it" ? What error/warning do you get?

Comment: show the declaration for identifier `natutalValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), missing the declaration for `NatutalValue`.

Filling in the blanks:

```
entity evaluate is
end entity;

architecture foo of evaluate is
    constant natutalValue:  integer := 4;
begin
    process 
    begin
        for j in 0 to 9 loop
            if j <= natutalValue then
                report "j = " &integer'image(j) &" do stuff";
            end if;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

> Macbook: ghdl -a evaluate.vhdl
>   Macbook: ghdl -e evaluate
>   Macbook: ghdl -r evaluate
>   evaluate.vhdl:11:17:@0ms:(report note): j = 0 do stuff
>   evaluate.vhdl:11:17:@0ms:(report note): j = 1 do stuff
>   evaluate.vhdl:11:17:@0ms:(report note): j = 2 do stuff
>   evaluate.vhdl:11:17:@0ms:(report note): j = 3 do stuff
>   evaluate.vhdl:11:17:@0ms:(report note): j = 4 do stuff

And it works. Which says the problem is in something you didn't show us.